# Add geotaged images to Leaflet

Tags: leaflet

I have a problem adding my images to the popup features of my Geojson. I can do it for one image but i would like to have them for multipels images.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>A Leaflet map!</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet.css" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="docs/images/favicon.ico" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.1.0/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-wcw6ts8Anuw10Mzh9Ytw4pylW8+NAD4ch3lqm9lzAsTxg0GFeJgoAtxuCLREZSC5lUXdVyo/7yfsqFjQ4S+aKw==" crossorigin=""/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.1.0/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-mNqn2Wg7tSToJhvHcqfzLMU6J4mkOImSPTxVZAdo+lcPlk+GhZmYgACEe0x35K7YzW1zJ7XyJV/TT1MrdXvMcA==" crossorigin=""></script>  
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.stamen.com/js/tile.stamen.js?v1.3.0"></script>
<style>

#myMapContainer {
border: red 1px solid;
width: 1880px;
height: 950px;
}
.leaflet-popup-content {
max-widthwidth: 1000px;
height: 600px;
overflow-y: scroll;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id='myMapContainer'></div>

<script>

// initialize the map
var myMap = L.map('myMapContainer', {
center: [49.806111111111107, 8.5986111111111114],
zoom: 30
});

var geojsonFeature = {
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"name": "bilder",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "ID": "5a7ff6d8-1697-4eac-937a-8f7183c56b2b", "Name": "20190826_093333.jpg", "Date": "2019\/08\/26", "Time": "09:33:33", "Lon": 8.5986111111111114, "Lat": 49.806111111111107, "Altitude": 159.0, "North": "", "Azimuth": "", "Camera Maker": "samsung", "Camera Model": "SM-G960F", "Title": "", "Comment": "", "Path": "C:\/Users\/abdul.sayed\/Desktop\/leaflet\/bilder\\20190826_093333.jpg", "RelPath": ".\/bilder\/20190826_093333.jpg", "Timestamp": "2019\/08\/26 09:33:33" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 8.598611111111111, 49.806111111111107 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "ID": "df988dff-7089-4f67-a91a-2c915b609849", "Name": "20190826_093334.jpg", "Date": "2019\/08\/26", "Time": "09:33:34", "Lon": 8.5986111111111114, "Lat": 49.806111111111107, "Altitude": 158.0, "North": "", "Azimuth": "", "Camera Maker": "samsung", "Camera Model": "SM-G960F", "Title": "", "Comment": "", "Path": "C:\/Users\/abdul.sayed\/Desktop\/leaflet\/bilder\\20190826_093334.jpg", "RelPath": ".\/bilder\/20190826_093334.jpg", "Timestamp": "2019\/08\/26 09:33:34" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 8.598611111111111, 49.806111111111107 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "ID": "42ceefde-fa04-41d1-9245-1b7df36f8513", "Name": "20190826_093351.jpg", "Date": "2019\/08\/26", "Time": "09:33:51", "Lon": 8.5988888888888901, "Lat": 49.806388888888883, "Altitude": 151.0, "North": "", "Azimuth": "", "Camera Maker": "samsung", "Camera Model": "SM-G960F", "Title": "", "Comment": "", "Path": "C:\/Users\/abdul.sayed\/Desktop\/leaflet\/bilder\\20190826_093351.jpg", "RelPath": ".\/bilder\/20190826_093351.jpg", "Timestamp": "2019\/08\/26 09:33:51" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 8.59888888888889, 49.806388888888883 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "ID": "af3843a5-8ce6-46e4-84aa-c57281b8abd7", "Name": "20190826_093353.jpg", "Date": "2019\/08\/26", "Time": "09:33:53", "Lon": 8.5988888888888901, "Lat": 49.806388888888883, "Altitude": 151.0, "North": "", "Azimuth": "", "Camera Maker": "samsung", "Camera Model": "SM-G960F", "Title": "", "Comment": "", "Path": "C:\/Users\/abdul.sayed\/Desktop\/leaflet\/bilder\\20190826_093353.jpg", "RelPath": ".\/bilder\/20190826_093353.jpg", "Timestamp": "2019\/08\/26 09:33:53" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 8.59888888888889, 49.806388888888883 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "ID": "57cf9f41-794e-4db0-b660-f6a65880cd21", "Name": "20190826_093355.jpg", "Date": "2019\/08\/26", "Time": "09:33:55", "Lon": 8.5988888888888901, "Lat": 49.806388888888883, "Altitude": 151.0, "North": "", "Azimuth": "", "Camera Maker": "samsung", "Camera Model": "SM-G960F", "Title": "", "Comment": "", "Path": "C:\/Users\/abdul.sayed\/Desktop\/leaflet\/bilder\\20190826_093355.jpg", "RelPath": ".\/bilder\/20190826_093355.jpg", "Timestamp": "2019\/08\/26 09:33:55" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 8.59888888888889, 49.806388888888883 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "ID": "45653ac0-acab-4637-a61e-11f90e0d3ee5", "Name": "20190826_093408.jpg", "Date": "2019\/08\/26", "Time": "09:34:08", "Lon": 8.5991666666666671, "Lat": 49.806388888888883, "Altitude": 155.0, "North": "", "Azimuth": "", "Camera Maker": "samsung", "Camera Model": "SM-G960F", "Title": "", "Comment": "", "Path": "C:\/Users\/abdul.sayed\/Desktop\/leaflet\/bilder\\20190826_093408.jpg", "RelPath": ".\/bilder\/20190826_093408.jpg", "Timestamp": "2019\/08\/26 09:34:08" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 8.599166666666667, 49.806388888888883 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "ID": "e39e9b1b-9b65-4b23-9f46-89759e2f9900", "Name": "20190826_093411.jpg", "Date": "2019\/08\/26", "Time": "09:34:11", "Lon": 8.5991666666666671, "Lat": 49.806388888888883, "Altitude": 155.0, "North": "", "Azimuth": "", "Camera Maker": "samsung", "Camera Model": "SM-G960F", "Title": "", "Comment": "", "Path": "C:\/Users\/abdul.sayed\/Desktop\/leaflet\/bilder\\20190826_093411.jpg", "RelPath": ".\/bilder\/20190826_093411.jpg", "Timestamp": "2019\/08\/26 09:34:11" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 8.599166666666667, 49.806388888888883 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "ID": "085b6d47-be69-4616-91b1-05ebf945e7a9", "Name": "20190826_093414.jpg", "Date": "2019\/08\/26", "Time": "09:34:14", "Lon": 8.5991666666666671, "Lat": 49.806388888888883, "Altitude": 155.0, "North": "", "Azimuth": "", "Camera Maker": "samsung", "Camera Model": "SM-G960F", "Title": "", "Comment": "", "Path": "C:\/Users\/abdul.sayed\/Desktop\/leaflet\/bilder\\20190826_093414.jpg", "RelPath": ".\/bilder\/20190826_093414.jpg", "Timestamp": "2019\/08\/26 09:34:14" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 8.599166666666667, 49.806388888888883 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "ID": "a150bb68-2a6e-4104-9194-893a3dbf92aa", "Name": "20190826_093427.jpg", "Date": "2019\/08\/26", "Time": "09:34:27", "Lon": 8.5991666666666671, "Lat": 49.806388888888883, "Altitude": 151.0, "North": "", "Azimuth": "", "Camera Maker": "samsung", "Camera Model": "SM-G960F", "Title": "", "Comment": "", "Path": "C:\/Users\/abdul.sayed\/Desktop\/leaflet\/bilder\\20190826_093427.jpg", "RelPath": ".\/bilder\/20190826_093427.jpg", "Timestamp": "2019\/08\/26 09:34:27" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 8.599166666666667, 49.806388888888883 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "ID": "a4ffe1b6-0d27-4d98-aa80-61a711f92fec", "Name": "20190826_093429.jpg", "Date": "2019\/08\/26", "Time": "09:34:29", "Lon": 8.5991666666666671, "Lat": 49.806388888888883, "Altitude": 156.0, "North": "", "Azimuth": "", "Camera Maker": "samsung", "Camera Model": "SM-G960F", "Title": "", "Comment": "", "Path": "C:\/Users\/abdul.sayed\/Desktop\/leaflet\/bilder\\20190826_093429.jpg", "RelPath": ".\/bilder\/20190826_093429.jpg", "Timestamp": "2019\/08\/26 09:34:29" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 8.599166666666667, 49.806388888888883 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "ID": "75a82be8-d11a-4907-b37e-7d14bf14d510", "Name": "20190826_093442.jpg", "Date": "2019\/08\/26", "Time": "09:34:42", "Lon": 8.5991666666666671, "Lat": 49.806388888888883, "Altitude": 157.0, "North": "", "Azimuth": "", "Camera Maker": "samsung", "Camera Model": "SM-G960F", "Title": "", "Comment": "", "Path": "C:\/Users\/abdul.sayed\/Desktop\/leaflet\/bilder\\20190826_093442.jpg", "RelPath": ".\/bilder\/20190826_093442.jpg", "Timestamp": "2019\/08\/26 09:34:42" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 8.599166666666667, 49.806388888888883 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "ID": "4eb3119f-c9c3-472f-8f5b-1e75b0f34671", "Name": "20190826_093444.jpg", "Date": "2019\/08\/26", "Time": "09:34:44", "Lon": 8.5991666666666671, "Lat": 49.806388888888883, "Altitude": 158.0, "North": "", "Azimuth": "", "Camera Maker": "samsung", "Camera Model": "SM-G960F", "Title": "", "Comment": "", "Path": "C:\/Users\/abdul.sayed\/Desktop\/leaflet\/bilder\\20190826_093444.jpg", "RelPath": ".\/bilder\/20190826_093444.jpg", "Timestamp": "2019\/08\/26 09:34:44" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 8.599166666666667, 49.806388888888883 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "ID": "ae71e289-1f59-4fee-a1f2-9735a76bfbbb", "Name": "20190826_093446.jpg", "Date": "2019\/08\/26", "Time": "09:34:46", "Lon": 8.5991666666666671, "Lat": 49.806388888888883, "Altitude": 158.0, "North": "", "Azimuth": "", "Camera Maker": "samsung", "Camera Model": "SM-G960F", "Title": "", "Comment": "", "Path": "C:\/Users\/abdul.sayed\/Desktop\/leaflet\/bilder\\20190826_093446.jpg", "RelPath": ".\/bilder\/20190826_093446.jpg", "Timestamp": "2019\/08\/26 09:34:46" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 8.599166666666667, 49.806388888888883 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "ID": "9e406746-f39d-45e6-9829-b4660eb9c783", "Name": "20190826_093501.jpg", "Date": "2019\/08\/26", "Time": "09:35:01", "Lon": 8.5994444444444458, "Lat": 49.806666666666665, "Altitude": 0.0, "North": "", "Azimuth": "", "Camera Maker": "samsung", "Camera Model": "SM-G960F", "Title": "", "Comment": "", "Path": "C:\/Users\/abdul.sayed\/Desktop\/leaflet\/bilder\\20190826_093501.jpg", "RelPath": ".\/bilder\/20190826_093501.jpg", "Timestamp": "2019\/08\/26 09:35:01" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 8.599444444444446, 49.806666666666665 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "ID": "3647e5f7-74c2-41c0-88b0-1ff90c503be4", "Name": "20190826_093511.jpg", "Date": "2019\/08\/26", "Time": "09:35:11", "Lon": 8.5994444444444458, "Lat": 49.806666666666665, "Altitude": 0.0, "North": "", "Azimuth": "", "Camera Maker": "samsung", "Camera Model": "SM-G960F", "Title": "", "Comment": "", "Path": "C:\/Users\/abdul.sayed\/Desktop\/leaflet\/bilder\\20190826_093511.jpg", "RelPath": ".\/bilder\/20190826_093511.jpg", "Timestamp": "2019\/08\/26 09:35:11" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 8.599444444444446, 49.806666666666665 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "ID": "a588e974-7f30-4d61-9fe8-5a9b9ab4776f", "Name": "20190826_093514.jpg", "Date": "2019\/08\/26", "Time": "09:35:14", "Lon": 8.5994444444444458, "Lat": 49.806666666666665, "Altitude": 0.0, "North": "", "Azimuth": "", "Camera Maker": "samsung", "Camera Model": "SM-G960F", "Title": "", "Comment": "", "Path": "C:\/Users\/abdul.sayed\/Desktop\/leaflet\/bilder\\20190826_093514.jpg", "RelPath": ".\/bilder\/20190826_093514.jpg", "Timestamp": "2019\/08\/26 09:35:14" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 8.599444444444446, 49.806666666666665 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "ID": "b2a386f5-6536-4976-8a26-c00d32a84fdc", "Name": "20190826_093521.jpg", "Date": "2019\/08\/26", "Time": "09:35:21", "Lon": 8.5994444444444458, "Lat": 49.806666666666665, "Altitude": 0.0, "North": "", "Azimuth": "", "Camera Maker": "samsung", "Camera Model": "SM-G960F", "Title": "", "Comment": "", "Path": "C:\/Users\/abdul.sayed\/Desktop\/leaflet\/bilder\\20190826_093521.jpg", "RelPath": ".\/bilder\/20190826_093521.jpg", "Timestamp": "2019\/08\/26 09:35:21" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 8.599444444444446, 49.806666666666665 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "ID": "5afb1b2e-4b6f-449b-bc26-dcd0afdf6c64", "Name": "20190826_093525.jpg", "Date": "2019\/08\/26", "Time": "09:35:25", "Lon": 8.5994444444444458, "Lat": 49.806666666666665, "Altitude": 0.0, "North": "", "Azimuth": "", "Camera Maker": "samsung", "Camera Model": "SM-G960F", "Title": "", "Comment": "", "Path": "C:\/Users\/abdul.sayed\/Desktop\/leaflet\/bilder\\20190826_093525.jpg", "RelPath": ".\/bilder\/20190826_093525.jpg", "Timestamp": "2019\/08\/26 09:35:25" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 8.599444444444446, 49.806666666666665 ] } }
]
};




// For one Image

var mypos = L.marker([50.068155, 8.430888]);

var OpenStreetMap_DE = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.de/tiles/osmde/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
maxZoom: 18,
attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
});

var imageUrl = 'bilder/20190826_093333.jpg',


imageBounds = [[50.068155, 8.430888], [50.068155, 8.430888]];

mypos.bindPopup("<img src='" + imageUrl + "'/>", {maxWidth: 1000}).openPopup();

L.geoJSON(geojsonFeature).addTo(myMap);



OpenStreetMap_DE.addTo(myMap);
L.imageOverlay(imageUrl, imageBounds).addTo(myMap);
mypos.addTo(myMap);





</script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome to GIS.SE! Could you please be more specific on your solution path or comment on your code?

Answer (score 1):

You need to place your pictures in a web folder. For example the first image:

"C:/Users/abdul.sayed/Desktop/leaflet/bilder\20190826_093333.jpg"

Well that's not on my C:\ drive, I won't see it. Change the data to just have the image name. 
Make a folder "photos" off your website. The have the JavaScript call it in the popup as

```
<img src='photos/" + feature.properties.YourPhotoField + "'>
```

Now how to show more than one photo in a popup? Here is a demo of a bootstrap dialog with tabs, you could have one phot in each tab.

Using a bootstrap dialog with Tabs http://www.gistechsolutions.com/leaflet/DEMO/pointsinpoly/indextab.html Zip file of my pages and datafiles. 
http://www.gistechsolutions.com/leaflet/DEMO/pointsinpoly/pointsinpoly.zip